# Wordpress Admin Pointers Does not hide

Tags: wordpress

WordPress introduces new feature for Admin & Plugin developers. Here is a little article about it if someone does not know what pointers are (http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-wordpress-pointers-in-your-own-plugins/)

Problem with me is, I am trying to add this in one of the plugin for WordPress. Pointer shows up at right place and hides when you click on it, but it **reappears** when you refreshes the page.

I am sharing code snippet below, maybe someone will be able to point the issue,as I was failed to do so. I have followed this tutorial to implement it: http://bavotasan.com/2013/working-with-custom-admin-pointers-in-wordpress/

Thanks

Here is code snippet:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_admin_pointers_header' );

function custom_admin_pointers_header() {
   if ( custom_admin_pointers_check() ) {
      add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'custom_admin_pointers_footer' );

      wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-pointer' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-pointer' );
   }
}

function custom_admin_pointers_check() {
   $admin_pointers = atomicReach_admin_pointers();
   foreach ( $admin_pointers as $pointer => $array ) {
      if ( $array['active'] )
         return true;
   }
}

function custom_admin_pointers_footer() {
   $admin_pointers = atomicReach_admin_pointers();
   ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
( function($) {
   <?php
   foreach ( $admin_pointers as $pointer => $array ) {
      if ( $array['active'] ) {
         ?>
         $( '<?php echo $array['anchor_id']; ?>' ).pointer( {
            content: '<?php echo $array['content']; ?>',
            position: {
            edge: '<?php echo $array['edge']; ?>',
            align: '<?php echo $array['align']; ?>'
         },
            close: function() {
               $.post( ajaxurl, {
                  pointer: '<?php echo $pointer; ?>',
                  action: 'dismiss-wp-pointer'
               } );
            }
         } ).pointer( 'open' );
         <?php
      }
   }
   ?>
} )(jQuery);
/* ]]> */
</script>
   <?php
}

function atomicReach_admin_pointers() {
   $dismissed = explode( ',', (string) get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'dismissed_wp_pointers', true ) );
   $version = '1_0'; // replace all periods in 1.0 with an underscore
   $prefix = 'atomicReach_admin_pointers' . $version . '_';

   $new_pointer_content = '<h3>' . __( 'my new headig' ) . '</h3>';
   $new_pointer_content .= '<p>' . __( 'my first new message' ) . '</p>';
   $new_pointer_content_analyzer = '<h3>' . __( 'my new heading' ) . '</h3>';
   $new_pointer_content_analyzer .= '<p>' . __( 'my new message' ) . '</p>';

   return array(
      $prefix . 'new_items' => array(
         'content' => $new_pointer_content,
         'anchor_id' => '#toplevel_page_ar-analyzer-admin',
         'edge' => 'left',
         'align' => 'left',
         'active' => ( ! in_array( $prefix . 'new_items', $dismissed ) )
      ),
    $prefix . 'analyzer_checkBox' => array(
         'content' => $new_pointer_content_analyzer,
         'anchor_id' => '#_ar_meta_review_enabled',
         'edge' => 'bottom',
         'align' => 'left',
         'active' => ( ! in_array( $prefix . 'analyzer_checkBox', $dismissed ) )
)
                 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add option and set the initial value to 0 and then add the following lines after position

```
close: function() {
                    <?php update_option("welcome_message",1) ?>
                }
```

then check if welcome message is 1 do not add pointer like this

```
if (get_option('welcome_message') == 0 ) 
            {
                add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', array( $this, 'pa_welcome_message' ) );
            }
```

otherwise do not add this hook.

here is complete code

```
if (get_option('pa_welcome_message') == 0 ) 
            {
                add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', array( $this, 'pa_welcome_message' ) );
            } 

public function pa_welcome_message() {
        $pointer_content = '<h3>Post Analytics</h3>';
        $pointer_content .= '<p>Thank you for activating Post analytics Plugin enjoy analytics right in your wordpress Dashboard</p>';
            ?>
           <script type="text/javascript">
           //<![CDATA[
           jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            $('#toplevel_page_pa-dashboard').pointer({
                content: '<?php echo $pointer_content; ?>',
                position: 'left',
                close: function() {
                    <?php update_option("pa_welcome_message",1) ?>
                }
              }).pointer('open');
           });
           //]]>
           </script>
    <?php
    }
```